# Prevent specific application information event IDs from Source Security-SPP flooding the Windows Application Event Viewer Log

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, eventviewer

Is there a way to prevent event IDs: 1003 and 1033 from Source: Security-SPP with Level: Information from flooding a Windows server Application Event Viewer Log?
I am seeing approx 4500 of these events logged daily and we do not need to see or log these particular Information events.
I know you can setup filters to filter out specific events when viewing the Application log but this does not stop the logging of these events bloating the application events log file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't a mechanism to prevent event(s) from being recorded in a Windows event log.